# Mysql: Find start of reoccuring events

Tags: mysql

My database has lots of timestamp-entries for voluntary workers: Let's call them "worker1" and "worker2".
I need to find when worker1 started to work and after that when worker2 started to work. (they work alternating one at a time) There can be several consecutive timestamps for the same worker.

```
(1, 1351508000, 'worker1'), 
(2, 1351508020, 'worker1'),  
(3, 1351508060, 'worker2'), 
(4, 1351508070, 'worker1'),  
(5, 1351508089, 'worker1'), 
(6, 1351508200, 'worker1'),  
(7, 1351508300, 'worker1'), 
(8, 1351508370, 'worker2'),   
(9, 1351508410, 'worker2'), 
(10,1351508450, 'worker2'),   
(11,1351508530, 'worker1'), 
(12,1351508700, 'worker2'),   
(13,1351508780, 'worker2')
```

So the result should be:

```
1351508000, 'worker1'
1351508060, 'worker2'
1351508070, 'worker1'
1351508370, 'worker2'
1351508530, 'worker1'
1351508700, 'worker2'
```

Thanks for helping us!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/483706/2

Comment: A data set, a desired result, *and* a fiddle. You're a star! Just one thing: where's your best effort to date?

Comment: I've added it to the fiddle. I absolutely don't have a clue how to get more than just the first or the last occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of the problem can be tackled this way...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,timestamp int NOT NULL
,worker char(38) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,  1351508000,     'worker1'), 
(2,   1351508020,     'worker1'),  
(3,   1351508060,     'worker2'), 
(4,   1351508070,     'worker1'),  
(5, 1351508089,     'worker1'), 
(6,   1351508200,     'worker1'),  
(7,   1351508300,     'worker1'), 
(8,   1351508370,     'worker2'),   
(9,   1351508410,     'worker2'), 
(10,  1351508450,     'worker2'),   
(11,  1351508530,     'worker1'), 
(12,  1351508540,     'worker2'),   
(13,  1351508580,     'worker2'), 
(14,  1351508600,     'worker2'),  
(15,  1351509290,     'worker2'), 
(16,  1351509380,     'worker1'),  
(17,  1351509390,     'worker1'),
(18,  1351509460,     'worker2'),  
(19,  1351509480,     'worker2'),  
(20,  1351509710,     'worker1'), 
(21,  1361510000,     'worker1'), 
(22,  1361510020,     'worker1'),   
(23,  1361510060,     'worker1'), 
(24,  1361510070,     'worker1') ;

SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev=worker THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
     , @prev:=worker
  FROM my_table x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp;
+----+------------+---------+------+---------------+
| id | timestamp  | worker  | i    | @prev:=worker |
+----+------------+---------+------+---------------+
|  1 | 1351508000 | worker1 |    1 | worker1       |
|  2 | 1351508020 | worker1 |    1 | worker1       |
|  3 | 1351508060 | worker2 |    2 | worker2       |
|  4 | 1351508070 | worker1 |    3 | worker1       |
|  5 | 1351508089 | worker1 |    3 | worker1       |
|  6 | 1351508200 | worker1 |    3 | worker1       |
|  7 | 1351508300 | worker1 |    3 | worker1       |
|  8 | 1351508370 | worker2 |    4 | worker2       |
|  9 | 1351508410 | worker2 |    4 | worker2       |
| 10 | 1351508450 | worker2 |    4 | worker2       |
| 11 | 1351508530 | worker1 |    5 | worker1       |
| 12 | 1351508540 | worker2 |    6 | worker2       |
| 13 | 1351508580 | worker2 |    6 | worker2       |
| 14 | 1351508600 | worker2 |    6 | worker2       |
| 15 | 1351509290 | worker2 |    6 | worker2       |
| 16 | 1351509380 | worker1 |    7 | worker1       |
| 17 | 1351509390 | worker1 |    7 | worker1       |
| 18 | 1351509460 | worker2 |    8 | worker2       |
| 19 | 1351509480 | worker2 |    8 | worker2       |
| 20 | 1351509710 | worker1 |    9 | worker1       |
| 21 | 1361510000 | worker1 |    9 | worker1       |
| 22 | 1361510020 | worker1 |    9 | worker1       |
| 23 | 1361510060 | worker1 |    9 | worker1       |
| 24 | 1361510070 | worker1 |    9 | worker1       |
+----+------------+---------+------+---------------+
```

From here, you can use the above as a subquery in a standard pattern for GROUPWISE MAX (or MIN), as follows...

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id 
         FROM
            ( SELECT x.*
                   , CASE WHEN @prev=worker THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
                   , @prev:=worker
                FROM my_table x
                   , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars
               ORDER 
                  BY timestamp
            ) n
        GROUP 
           BY i
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id;

+----+------------+---------+
| id | timestamp  | worker  |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 1351508000 | worker1 |
|  3 | 1351508060 | worker2 |
|  4 | 1351508070 | worker1 |
|  8 | 1351508370 | worker2 |
| 11 | 1351508530 | worker1 |
| 12 | 1351508540 | worker2 |
| 16 | 1351509380 | worker1 |
| 18 | 1351509460 | worker2 |
| 20 | 1351509710 | worker1 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Adding a "group by i" brings up the wanted result!

Comment: @Clain29 Adding a GROUP BY in that way actually produces an indeterminate result. You're relying on an undocumented hack (unless you count the comments section of the manual) to produce that result. I'll amend my answer with a documented approach...